# Transforming a binary file into a decimal format using bash, how to?

Tags: linux, bash, file, unix, decimal

I have a binary file generated by my program, but I need to compare its decimal contents to check if they meet my requirements. However, I can't seem to find a way to do this using bash, is there any code that lets me get this done? Whenever I open it using a program like sublime text I get the contents in HEX form; however, I am not looking for that.

```
5249 4646 5200 0000 5741 5645 666d 7420
1000 0000 0100 0200 44ac 0000 10b1 0200
0400 1000 6461 7461 2e00 0000 0200 0200
0200 0300 0300 0900 0900 0900 0c00 0c00
1400 1400 1400 1800 1800 0c00 0c00 0c00
0600 0600 0200 0200 0200
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "decimal contents"?  If you convert 4 bits at a time you get a hex digit, if you convert 3 bits at a time you get an octal digit.

Comment: .... the above comment doesnt make any sense whatsoever. Sorry but number systems dont work that way.

Comment: Have you tried using 'strings' on the file? To be honest, this looks like a text file, not a binary file, if you can put it into a text editor and get numbers and letters out. So 'strings' probably won't work. You probably need to loop through and echo out into decimal format. Here is a quick tutorial I found: http://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2008/04/quick-hex-decimal-conversion-using-cli.html

Comment: The file is a wav file

Comment: In order to get a better answer, please edit your question to explain your use case and desired solution more clearly. Providing what you are seeing and an example of what you want to see will help the community help you.

Comment: Or, since you know the decimal values you need, why not convert them to hex and see if the values match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash, simply type

```
xxd -b yourbinaryfile
```

Comment: This works in binary, is there any command that lets me convert these to decimal?

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean with decimal then. A binary file is just... binary. Decimal to me means: digits from 0 to 9. They are characters used in common language and have a hexadecimal representation when converted with a code table (e.g. UTF8). Can you clarify the contents of the binary file and give an example of how you want it represented?

Comment: @NonPlusUltra Hexadecimal: `0xff`, binary: `0b11111111`, decimal: `255`. So the output should be numbers from 0 to 256 exclusive.

Answer (score 10):

For a dump of bytes in decimal:

`od -t u1 filename`

For a dump of 2-byte words in decimal:

`od -t u2 filename`